# Get 2nd Recent task (android)

Tags: android, task

I'm trying to get the package name of the second recent app (so not the app currently running).

Now I have come this far:

```
                final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                final List<RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRecentTasks(20, ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED);

                for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) {

                    Intent baseIntent = recentTasks.get(i).baseIntent;
                    if(baseIntent != null) {

                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName();

                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();

                    }
```

But this will show all recent tasks.

If anyone knows how to show only the second last task, instead of all tasks, your help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get Second Recent Task from Activity Stack try it as:

```
 List<RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRecentTasks(2, 
                                         ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED);

if(recentTasks.size() >= 1) {
    RecentTaskInfo SecondrecentTask = recentTasks.get(1);
    Intent baseIntent = SecondrecentTask.baseIntent;
    //....do your work here..

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm getting "Invalid index 2, size is 2" any idea?

Comment: @Mark029348 : yes use 1 instead of 2 because List indexing starting from 0 instead of 1

Comment: @Mark029348 : but in getRecentTasks method you will need to pass 2 as first parameter if you want to get only top two recent tasks from Activity Stack

Answer (score 0):

You are looping and toasting, so you show all items present in recentTask.

The second item would probably be:

```
recentTasks.get(1);
```